# set the starting row value in dropdown box in php

Tags: php, html

I've got a table with dates:

**id,datefield,dayfield,monthyearfield**

1,2012-05-01,Tuesday,May-2012

2,2012-05-02,Wednesday,May-2012

I'm using a dropdownbox where I select DISTINCT monthyearfield.  If the month is for instance Jun-2012 I want the dropdownbox to default to that when the page opens.  I don't know how to do that.  If I use a WHERE clause it only shows for instance Jun-2012.  Currently it is defaulting to the first row, which is May-2012.  I tried ORDER BY variable ($date_start1) but that is not working.

```
<?php
$date_start1 = "Jun-2012"; //just for testing purposes, will change later so that it gets the current Month.
echo $date_start1;
$sql2 = "SELECT DISTINCT monthyearfield FROM trn_cal";
$res2 = mysql_query($sql2);
echo "<form method='post'>";
$dropdown = "<select name='myvalue'>";
while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($res2)) {
    $my = $row2['monthyearfield'];
    $dropdown .= "\r\n<option value='{$row2['id']}'>{$row2['monthyearfield']}</option>";
}
$dropdown .= "\r\n</select>";
echo $dropdown;
echo "<input type=submit name=Submit value='Go'>";
$data1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["myvalue"]);
echo "</form>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($res2)) {
    $my = $row2['monthyearfield'];
    $selected = "";
    if ( $my == $date_start1 ) {
      $selected = " selected='selected'";
    }
    $dropdown .= "\r\n<option value='{$row2['id']}'{$selected}>{$row2['monthyearfield']}</option>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use php [`date`*<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function
and add a if to check it.
like:

```
$cur_date = date('M-Y');
while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($res2)) {       
    $selected = "";
    if ($row2['monthyearfield'] == $cur_date) {
       $selected = "selected='selected'";
    }
    $dropdown .= "\r\n<option value='{$row2['id']}' {$selected}>{$row2['monthyearfield']}</option>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just edit this line:

```
$dropdown .= "\r\n<option value='{$row2['id']}'>{$row2['monthyearfield']}";
```

> if  ($row2['monthyearfield']== 'Jun-2012') 
>      $dropdown .="selected=selected";
>
> $dropdown .=' /option> ';

Answer (score 0):

do you want to order your results, or do you want to automaticly select a specific item in your option-list? i suggest it is the last one, or isn't it?

so, give the ""-tag, which contains the value which should be automaticly selected, the "selected='selected' atttribute/value.

f.e.:

```
<select>
    <option>Bar</option>
    <option selected="selected">Foo</option>
    <option>FooBar</option>
</select>
```

So the item with the title "Foo" will be automaticly selected.